# Error in update query in Entity Framework and data model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
database.Database.SqlQuery<zamenin>("update zamenin set shomaremoshtarevamgirande ='" + txt_customnum.Text.Trim() + "' where shomaremoshtarevamgirande='" + shomaremoshtare + "'").ToList();
database.SaveChanges();
```

When I run this code I get this error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'moavaghatModel.zamenin'. A member of the type, 'ID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SqlQuery<zamenin>()` expects the query to return a data set that contains rows that match the `zamenin` type. However, you are running an update statement which does not return data.

To run an update statement, you should do this:

```
database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("update zamenin set shomaremoshtarevamgirande ='" + txt_customnum.Text.Trim() + "' where shomaremoshtarevamgirande='" + shomaremoshtare + "'")
```

A more secure way is to use parameterized queries like this:

```
database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("update zamenin set shomaremoshtarevamgirande = {0} where shomaremoshtarevamgirande= {1}", txt_customnum.Text.Trim(), shomaremoshtare);
```

You also do not need to call `SaveChanges()` because `ExecuteSqlCommand()` runs immediately.